# Playing a sound file has side effects

Tags: javascript

I added this to a condition on my site:

```
$("body").append('<embed src="Sound.wav" autostart="true" hidden="true"></embed>');
```

and it worked, but the page stopped accepting input after the sound played.
This is for an in-house application, so I can specify which browser and version the person has to use.

Q: Why did [the page](http://www.cfmzengarden.com/BarCodeZenGarden/001/001.cfm) stop accepting input into the text input field?

Comment: The text input field works for me, but 4 `<embed>` tags appeared randomly. You should scrap the jquery.sound.js route and try something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EEK. If you want to play a sound in a web browser, IMHO there is only one easy, cross-browser, glitch-free way to do it properly. That's to use [SoundManager 2](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/). I'm really not sure why you're experiencing the behavior you are, but you can expect to encounter other strange results as you view the page in different browsers and browser versions.

Comment: You see?  THAT'S why I ask questions on Stackoverflow!